# Chromecast SDK with m3u8 urls

Tags: javascript, google-cast, chromecast, m3u8

I have setup the example webserver that comes with the SDK (https://github.com/googlecast/), and it works will the [example media file](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/) they provide. When I try it with an [example m3u8](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8) file it fails with:

```
{"code":"session_error","description":"LOAD_FAILED","details":null}`
```

Both URLs load fine in Safari. Is this type of streaming media not supported? Is there a way to get a more detailed error message.

Comment: Joining in... same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The streaming media requires the Cast [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) to be used.  See the [sample](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Media-Player-Library-Sample).

To get more debugging information, add  `?Debug=true` to your URL in the [developers console](https://cast.google.com/publish), as well as your device.  Then using [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging), connect to your Chromecast using the URL **IP of Chromecast:9222** look at the console.

Comment: Why does pychromecast work with the default media reciever app?